# Do I need a new SSN after changing visa types?

Tags: usa, h1-visa, social-security, j-visa

I've been living and working in the US on a J-1 visa for the last year. I've just entered the US on my new H1-B visa and will start work on October 1st. Do I need to get a new SSN, or can I use the one I already have from my J-1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SSN never changes once assigned, and your immigration status has no effect on it.

Comment: SSNs **can** be changed in a few special cases but that's because of the misuse of the old one, not your immigration status.

Comment: For the purpose of this answer we can disregard this (or any other way to change SSN, like getting into a witness protection program etc). These are marginal and irrelevant cases.

Comment: The number will never change, but sometimes you need to change the card itself, due annotations you have on them (like *"not valid for work"* or such).